# Laravel Eloquent compare two columns does not not work

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a weird eloquent bug.

In my customer_order_lines table I have two columns qty_reserve and qty_in_pick_up.
Both are integer

For example, in the database I have one line

| product_id | qty_reserve | qty_in_pick_up |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 4 |

In eloquent I try to load the line that qty_reserve are not equal to qty_in_pick_up

```
$lines = CustomerOrderLine::where('qty_reserve','!=','qty_in_pick_up')->get();
```

But for an unknow reason this load the line where both qty_reserve and qty_in_pick_up are equal to 4.

But if I do the same but with whereRaw it's working

```
$lines = CustomerOrderLine::whereRaw('qty_in_pick_up != qty_reserve')->get();
```

Anyone has an idea why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$lines = CustomerOrderLine::where('qty_reserve','!=','qty_in_pick_up')->get();
```

This can't work, because `where()` waiting for the value for the third parameter.

You can use `whereColumn('qty_reserve', '!=', 'qty_in_pick_up');`

Answer (score 0):

After posting my question, I add a flash on the where clause.
I check the Laravel documentation and where expect the second argument/third to be a value not and other columns

I tried the whereColumn and it solves my problem.
It's cleaner than the whereRaw and expect a column as a second/third argument.

I leave the answer here if that help someone else.